How can ı access method from one statefulWidget in another Widget for canvas
ı create canvas for users can draw.And ı am trying to do use in that canvas another screen. I add button for clear. But ı cant access the clear method,
when I looked at the previous opened questions on stackoverflow, I saw that it is used in InheritedWidget. at first I used an object from my canvas class, but I couldn't see the method.
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../../core/util/app_sizes.dart';

class ThetaCanvas extends StatefulWidget {
  const ThetaCanvas({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ThetaCanvas> createState() => _ThetaCanvasState();
}

class _ThetaCanvasState extends State<ThetaCanvas> {
  List<DrawingArea?> points = [];
  late double opacity;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    opacity = 1.0;
  }

   clearThetaCanvas() {
    setState(() {
      points.clear();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRect(
      child: Container(
        height: AppSizes.screenHeight / 4,
        width: AppSizes.screenWidth,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white70, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onPanDown: (details) {
            setState(() {
              points.add(DrawingArea(
                point: details.localPosition,
                areaPaint: Paint()
                  ..color = Colors.black.withOpacity(opacity)
                  ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
                  ..isAntiAlias = true
                  ..strokeWidth = 2.0,
              ));
            });
          },
          onPanUpdate: (details) {
            setState(() {
              points.add(DrawingArea(
                point: details.localPosition,
                areaPaint: Paint()
                  ..color = Colors.black.withOpacity(opacity)
                  ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
                  ..isAntiAlias = true
                  ..strokeWidth = 2.0,
              ));
            });
          },
          onPanEnd: (details) {
            points.add(null);
          },
          child: CustomPaint(
            size: Size.infinite,
            painter: DrawingPainter(pointsList: points),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DrawingPainter extends CustomPainter {
  List<DrawingArea?> pointsList;

  DrawingPainter({required this.pointsList});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pointsList.length - 1; i++) {
      if (pointsList[i] != null && pointsList[i + 1] != null) {
        canvas.drawLine(
          pointsList[i]!.point,
          pointsList[i + 1]!.point,
          pointsList[i]!.areaPaint,
        );
      } else if (pointsList[i] != null && pointsList[i + 1] == null) {
        canvas.drawPoints(PointMode.points, [pointsList[i]!.point], pointsList[i]!.areaPaint);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

class DrawingArea {
  Offset point;
  Paint areaPaint;

  DrawingArea({required this.point, required this.areaPaint});
}


and here is my button

class NextAndClearButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const NextAndClearButton({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThetaCanvas thetaCanvas = ThetaCanvas();

    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        
      },
      style: ButtonStyle(
        splashFactory: InkRipple.splashFactory,
        overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
              return Colors.white
                  .withOpacity(0.4); 
            }
            return Colors.transparent; 
          },
        ),
      ),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white), 
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25), 
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, 
          children: [
            Text(
              'NEXT',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displaySmall?.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            const Icon(
              Icons.chevron_right_outlined,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 40,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

when ı write the thetaCanvas.clearThetaCanvas its says
The method 'clearThetaCanvas' isn't defined for the type 'ThetaCanvas'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'clearThetaCanvas'

clearThetaCanvas is declared in the State of the widget, but not the widget itself. However, it won't work anyway since you are creating a new instance of ThetaCanvas which is not the same rendered one. How do you use the NextAndClearButton widget?

ı use another stateful widget class ThetaScreenInteractive extends StatefulWidget {
const ThetaScreenInteractive({super.key});
@override
State createState() => _ThetaScreenInteractiveState();
}
class _ThetaScreenInteractiveState extends State {
bool isPressed = false;
void changeButtons() {
setState(() {
isPressed = !isPressed;
});
} and there is a column     ....ThetaCanvas(),
Align(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, child: NextButton())
],

so what should ı use statemanangment ? or anythink like that ?

So why don't you have NextAndClearButton inside ThetaCanvas? and when tapping it you call clearThetaCanvas...

The issue you're facing is due to the fact that the ThetaCanvas widget doesn't directly expose the clearThetaCanvas method. The method is defined within the _ThetaCanvasState class, and it's not accessible from outside the state class in a straightforward manner.
To solve this problem, you can use the GlobalKey to get access to the state of the ThetaCanvas widget and call the clearThetaCanvas method. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:
Define a GlobalKey for your ThetaCanvas widget.
Use this key to access the state and call the clearThetaCanvas method from your button.
Here's the updated code:
ThetaCanvas Widget
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../../core/util/app_sizes.dart';

class ThetaCanvas extends StatefulWidget {
  const ThetaCanvas({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ThetaCanvas> createState() => _ThetaCanvasState();
}

class _ThetaCanvasState extends State<ThetaCanvas> {
  List<DrawingArea?> points = [];
  late double opacity;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    opacity = 1.0;
  }

  void clearThetaCanvas() {
    setState(() {
      points.clear();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRect(
      child: Container(
        height: AppSizes.screenHeight / 4,
        width: AppSizes.screenWidth,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white70, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onPanDown: (details) {
            setState(() {
              points.add(DrawingArea(
                point: details.localPosition,
                areaPaint: Paint()
                  ..color = Colors.black.withOpacity(opacity)
                  ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
                  ..isAntiAlias = true
                  ..strokeWidth = 2.0,
              ));
            });
          },
          onPanUpdate: (details) {
            setState(() {
              points.add(DrawingArea(
                point: details.localPosition,
                areaPaint: Paint()
                  ..color = Colors.black.withOpacity(opacity)
                  ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
                  ..isAntiAlias = true
                  ..strokeWidth = 2.0,
              ));
            });
          },
          onPanEnd: (details) {
            points.add(null);
          },
          child: CustomPaint(
            size: Size.infinite,
            painter: DrawingPainter(pointsList: points),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DrawingPainter extends CustomPainter {
  List<DrawingArea?> pointsList;

  DrawingPainter({required this.pointsList});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pointsList.length - 1; i++) {
      if (pointsList[i] != null && pointsList[i + 1] != null) {
        canvas.drawLine(
          pointsList[i]!.point,
          pointsList[i + 1]!.point,
          pointsList[i]!.areaPaint,
        );
      } else if (pointsList[i] != null && pointsList[i + 1] == null) {
        canvas.drawPoints(PointMode.points, [pointsList[i]!.point], pointsList[i]!.areaPaint);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

class DrawingArea {
  Offset point;
  Paint areaPaint;

  DrawingArea({required this.point, required this.areaPaint});
}

NextAndClearButton Widget
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'theta_canvas.dart'; // Ensure this is the correct path

class NextAndClearButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<_ThetaCanvasState> canvasKey;

  const NextAndClearButton({super.key, required this.canvasKey});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        canvasKey.currentState?.clearThetaCanvas();
      },
      style: ButtonStyle(
        splashFactory: InkRipple.splashFactory,
        overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
              return Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4); 
            }
            return Colors.transparent; 
          },
        ),
      ),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white), 
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25), 
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, 
          children: [
            Text(
              'NEXT',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displaySmall?.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            const Icon(
              Icons.chevron_right_outlined,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 40,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Wherever you are using ThetaCanvas and NextAndClearButton, pass the `GlobalKey.
For example if you are using from your main then you can follow this code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'theta_canvas.dart';
import 'next_and_clear_button.dart'; // Ensure this is the correct path

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<_ThetaCanvasState> canvasKey = GlobalKey<_ThetaCanvasState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Drawing App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            ThetaCanvas(key: canvasKey),
            NextAndClearButton(canvasKey: canvasKey),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


first of all thank you for time but it didnt work ı write       final GlobalKey<_ThetaCanvasState> canvasKey = GlobalKey<_ThetaCanvasState>();
but it says "The name '_ThetaCanvasState' isn't a type, so it can't be used as a type argument.
Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named '_ThetaCanvasState'"

The name '_ThetaCanvasState' isn't a type, so it can't be used as a type argument.
Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named '_ThetaCanvasState'
